# Type Mismatch while converting string to int in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to add values of two column after converting from string to int using withcolumn in spark sql.

```
withColumn("totalDowntimetime",("zenerTime").cast(int)+("avalancheTime").cast(int)).show(truncate = false)
```

but it is throwing error as "

```
 Error:(36, 44) type mismatch;
     found   : String("zenerTime")
     required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
        withColumn("totalDowntimetime",("zenerTime").cast(int)+("avalancheTime").cast(int)).show(truncate = false)
```

Very Much Appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try refering your columns `zenerTime`,`avalancheTime`  with **`col(<column_name>)`**

- As required type is **`column`**

---

```
withColumn("totalDowntimetime",col("zenerTime").cast(int) + col("avalancheTime").cast(int)).show(truncate = false)
```

Example:

```
val df=Seq(("1","2")).toDF("zenerTime","avalancheTime")


import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

df.withColumn("totalDowntimetime",col("zenerTime").cast("int") + col("avalancheTime").cast("int")).show()
/*
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|zenerTime|avalancheTime|totalDowntimetime|
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|        1|            2|                3|
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
*/
```

Comment: not sure why i am getting error as cannot resolve overload method cast.... any specific library , do i need to import.

Comment: I have added `Example` section in the answer try by importing `functions and types`.